# I need to create webpart to display % of project completed from project server value into my share point 2010 page?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I need to create webpart to display % of project completed from project server value into my share point 2010 page ?

Comment: Do you want to build such a free web part like SharePoint project progress monitor? I know your requirement is much more than this but I do not believe that worth your effort, Hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Business Connectivity Services (BCS). You can manage External Content Types to use data from external sources in SharePoint (and especially WebParts).

Comment: I am following the same way.using stored procedure i am returning the table. i need to pass the parameter to stored procedure . ow to do that any sample reference u have?

Comment: I was following the guide that you can find here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cffb14e8-88a9-43bd-87aa-4792ab60d320
Have a look at the example 2 in the developer walkthrough guide document.